# How to connect WordPress / WooCommerce to a REST API with PHP?

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to write my first REST API with PHP. We want to send shipping data to the shipping company and get labels for printing in return. The shipping company has given me test api credentials.

So I started to write a plugin with this code inside:

```
$url      = "https://mywebsite/endpoint/";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";

$data = array( 
     'key1' => 'value1', 
     'key2' => 'value2'
);

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'body'    => $data,
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password ),
        ),
    ) 
);

var_dump($response); // not being called
```

When I run this code, I get a white screen with no error message, the last line with var_dump($response) is not being called. I am a bit stuck here because I se no success and no error...what could it be? Why this behaviour of the remote server? Does it mean "sorry, wrong credentials" or "data has the wrong format"? I have the feeling that the server doesn't even notice that I'm trying to contact him...

I tried a number of other variatons of the above code that I found somwehere online, and also outside of WordPress, but no success.

The shipping company gave me a documentation. It says:

HTTP Method: POST
Authentication Header: Basic Authentication (user name/ password)

so I thought I could do no wrong when trying that. Hm.

Comment: All the best - https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it apppears to be the answer to a different question. I want to connect WooCommerce to a remote server. Your link tells me how a remote server connects to WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, so I can share it here with you.

I installed the free Software **Postman** and created a simple POST query there. After entering $url, $username and $password I ran a query and it worked well. the good thing abort Postman is that it creates code snippets for you. "very_long_cryptic_string" is obviously created from $username and $password. The PHP for my case goes like this, and it works:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Authorization: Basic very_long_cryptic_string'
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```